# PHP Data Extraction From External Website, Then Write to Database

Tags: php, file-get-contents, data-extraction

Just wondering how this would be done. Let's say there's a simple HTML table on an external website, and you have a database with the same structure as that HTML table. I understand that you can use `file_get_contents` to grab that entire web page.

From there, I would assume that you would remove everything from your `file_get_contents` except for the stuff between the `<table></table>` tags, thus isolating the table containing the data you wish to write.

What is the next step? Assuming your database table structure matches the structure of the HTML table, what would be the easiest way to write the table data into your database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this will be of interest(hope so lol), a super simple class to parse html.

Using only DOMDocument and cURL

```
<?php 
$scraper = new DOMScraper();
//example couldent think of a site with an example table
$scraper->setSite('http://cherone.co.uk/forum')->setSource();

//all tables on page
echo '<table>'.$scraper->getInnerHTML('table').'</table>';

//get only tables with id="some_table_id" or any attribute match eg class="somthing"
echo '<table>'.$scraper->getInnerHTML('table','id=some_table_id').'</table>';

//get all tables contents but return only nodeValue/text
echo '<table>'.$scraper->getInnerHTML('table','id=some_table_id',true).'</table>';


/**
 * Generic DOM scapper using DOMDocument and cURL
 */
Class DOMScraper extends DOMDocument{
    public $site;
    private $source;
    private $dom;

    function __construct(){
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $this->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $this->strictErrorChecking = false;
    }

    function setSite($site){
        $this->site = $site;
        return $this;
    }

    function setSource(){
        if(empty($this->site))return 'Error: Missing $this->site, use setSite() first';
        $this->source = $this->get_data($this->site);
        return $this;
    }

    function getInnerHTML($tag, $id=null, $nodeValue = false){
        if(empty($this->site))return 'Error: Missing $this->source, use setSource() first';
        $this->loadHTML($this->source);
        $tmp = $this->getElementsByTagName($tag);
        $ret = null;
        foreach ($tmp as $v){
            if($id !== null){
                $attr = explode('=',$id);
                if($v->getAttribute($attr[0])==$attr[1]){
                    if($nodeValue == true){
                        $ret .= trim($v->nodeValue);
                    }else{
                        $ret .= $this->innerHTML($v);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if($nodeValue == true){
                    $ret .= trim($v->nodeValue);
                }else{
                    $ret .= $this->innerHTML($v);
                }
            }
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    function innerHTML($dom){
        $ret = "";
        $nodes = $dom->childNodes;
        foreach($nodes as $v){
            $tmp = new DOMDocument();
            $tmp->appendChild($tmp->importNode($v, true));
            $ret .= trim($tmp->saveHTML());
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    function get_data($url){
        if(function_exists('curl_init')){
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
        }else{
            return file_get_contents($url);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm getting 500 internal server errors whenever I try to use DOM...any idea why?

Comment: check your error log, could be that curls not installed. ill update the code

Comment: I've verified that curl is installed. Enabled errors and got this: Fatal error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /var/www/html/test/index.php on line 27. Fixed this with `yum install php-xml`

Comment: Test if installed `echo (class_exists("DOMDocument")) ? "Installed" : "Not installed";` if its not install it or ask your host to.

Comment: I got it figured out, I'm now displaying the table on my website. However, how would I write the contents to database?

Comment: I suggest you look up PDO and use that over the deprecated `mysql_*` functions before you start to code, a great tut can be found [here](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html), you can build a model class like the above that holds various types of methods that do specific actions on your db, hope it helps

Comment: I actually use `mysqli_`, never really done anything with PDO before. I'll look into it though, thanks

Comment: I figured it out using Simple HTML DOM: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for example